# Как вывести DIV по условию?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Подскажите как показать DIV после 6 элемента формирующегося из кода:

```
<?php if(count($this->items)): ?>
<div class="tagItemList">
    <?php foreach($this->items as $item): ?>
```

так чтобы после 6 элемента выводился div и затем по умолчанию остальные элементы предусмотренные функционалом кода. Спасибо

Comment: Установите счетчик, инкрементируйте его при выводе, и если условие совпало - выводите элемент.

Comment: Спасибо @Firepro. Но возникла проблема. Заменяю код на ваш и все вместе выглядит так:   '<?php if(count($this->items)): ?>
 <div class="tagItemList">
  <?php
  $i = 0;
  foreach($this->items as $item) {
         if (++$i==7) {
            echo "<div>1</div>";
      }
   }
  ?>'     Получаю syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach'  на строке   с <?php endforeach; ?> . что я делаю не верно?

Comment: Сорри, Сделал, как Вы сказали:  <?php if(count($this->items)): ?>  
 <div class="tagItemList">  
  <?php
         $i = 0;  
   foreach($this->items as $item):   
       if (++$i==7) {  
             echo "<div>1</div>";  
             }  
   ?>   Ошибка пропала, но в исходный код див не добавляется

Comment: значит, что скорее всего оператор $i не доходит до 7, сделайте его вывод в цикле echo $i, после foreach и посмотрите до какого числа доходит данный оператор

Comment: :( попробовал поизменять код по-разному насколько смог понять что нужно сделать из предыдущего комента и что-то вообще буксанул. с php практически не знаком. сорри...

Comment: Обновил свой ответ, постарался описать Вам подробно решение вашей задачи

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ. Сделал правки. и обнаружил что код срабатывает не на всех страницах, а только на некоторых, при этом вывод дива произвольный, то есть не после 6 элемента, а может после 2 или после 10...по разному! Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$i = 0;

foreach($this->items as $item) {
    //делаем пост-инкремент и сравниваем значение
    if (++$i==7) {
       echo "<div>Я тот блок, который будет выведен после 6 элемента, 
       то есть буду седьмым </div>";
    }
}
```

Мы с Вами пообщались в комментариях и вы сообщили о том, что плохо знакомы с PHP, я расскажу более подробно по вашей задаче решение.

Ваш код по сути в первом условии смотрит, что в массиве this-items есть какие-то элементы (размер массива больше 0), и если это так, выводит div с класом: tagItemList, после чего начинается перебор массива $this->items последовательно.

```
<?php if(count($this->items)): ?> //условие
<div class="tagItemList"> //вывод элемента
    <?php foreach($this->items as $item): ?> //перебор массива
```

В вашем скрипте используется альтернативный способ определения управляющих конструкций, о котором вы можете почитать [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).  В каждом случае основной формой альтернативного синтаксиса является изменение открывающей фигурной скобки на двоеточие (:), а закрывающей скобки на endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach; или endswitch; соответственно.

Следовательно, ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы перебрать элементы массива items и на 7 элемент вывести какой-то div. И так, для начала проверьте, сработает ли у Вас данное условие.

```
<?php if(count($this->items)): ?> 
<div class="tagItemList">
    <?php 
          $i = 0; 
          foreach($this->items as $item): 
                  $i++;
                  echo "i = ".$i." ";
    ?>
```

Условие сработает, если в коде у Вас появилось i = 7, тогда ниже можно вставить код, который будет выводить требуемый div (и благодаря этому можно определить какой граничный i будет выведен)

```
  <?php if(count($this->items)): ?> 
    <div class="tagItemList">
        <?php 
              $i = 0; 
              foreach($this->items as $item): 
                     if (++$i==7):
                          echo "<div>1</div>";
                      endif;
        ?>
```

Этот вариант проверки переменных самый простой, хотя конечно для дебага пользоваться различными расширениями, которые помогают следить за ходом выполнения программы.